# How did Malcolm Crowe enter Sears' house without knowing his status?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sixth-sense

In the 1999 film, *The Sixth Sense*, Malcolm Crowe is…

> killed by a former patient and becomes a ghost. However, he doesn't realize this until the end of the movie. Also, he isn't seen by anyone except for Cole Sear who is his new patient.

My question is about just minutes before the scene when Cole steps to the room of their house after speaking with his mother. He suddenly sees Malcolm sitting on the chair waiting for him.

I think the only way for him to enter a house is to knock the door or ring the doorbell.

So I imagine he knocked the door or rang the doorbell. Then Cole's mother opened the door and saw **nobody**. So she got confused and stepped out of the house moving her head to right and left to see who has just rung the bell or knocked the door. In this situation Malcolm says hi to her with no response. Then he enters the house.

How did he not suspect something is odd when he realized Cole's mother can't see him?

Also, when Cole's mother had sat in front of Malcolm, he again didn't realize he isn't seen by her.

Comment: We don't mind spoilers in the body of the question but try to avoid in the title.  Normally for a move that is nearly 25 years old I wouldn't mind that much, but this twist is almost the entire point of the movie.

Comment: Ankit's edit took the spoiler out of the title but you could still be spoiled from the landing page. I'm not much of a fan of spoiler tags, especially on old movies, but this one is really the 'whole point of the plot' so I've buried it in this instance.

Comment: There are a bunch of things that don't make sense once you know the twist.

Comment: When nothing makes sense remember what Cole said: "They don't see each other. They only see what they want to see. They don't know they're dead."

Comment: I agree with Ankit - I always assumed dead people experience the world like a dream and like a dream it can be very hard to see it’s not real/they’re not alive. Malcolm might have just appeared in Cole’s house without realizing it or trying to remember how he got there. Remember he goes to and from his basement without noticing the door is blocked until the end. He only sees what he wants to see - which means he doesn’t see things that would make him realize he’s dead.

Comment: For that matter, how did he get into the restaurant apparently having dinner with his wife? Getting in and out of buildings does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Restaurant is a public place. Its door isn't locked. But a private house like the Sears' has a locked door and it's opened only when you ask the house owner via knocking the door or ringing the bell.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Wasn't that blocked door just the door of a room? Your comment seems to suggest that was the main door of the basement.

Comment: I’ve always thought that was the door to the basement. If it’s not, why does it matter that it’s blocked? It wouldn’t make sense to feature that door being impassable in the film if we didn’t know he’d actually gone through it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Remember that he always was trying to open that door, but always gived up and left the scene and went down the stairs when he couldn't. I think that was Malcolm's private room which his wife blocked it so that she doesn't have to go into it and remember of his deceased husband. Also, if that is the door to the basement why should his wife block and unblock it every time she wants to go in and out?

Comment: I thought the basement and his private room were the same thing. Which would explain why she would block it